# Is there a way to update a user's view when someone makes a change on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make a basic version of twitter using the rails framework. I have completed the basic stuff and deployed the site on heroku but I found a problem regarding posting. For example when two people are using the site and one of them makes a post the other cannot see it unless he refreshes the page manually. I wanted to know if there is a way that makes rails check if there was a change and updates the view accordingly.
My code: https://github.com/Abhimanyu-dev/Members-Only
Deployed site: https://members4841.herokuapp.com/
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is exactly the problem that hotwire was added in Rails 7, checkout hotwired.dev

Comment: sorry you got downvotes, it's a reasonable question. In my previous comment I meant to say "this is exactly the problem that hotwire was added to solve in Rails 7"

Comment: Like the answer above, you could use WebSockets to achieve that
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding this gems to your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  ......
  gem "guard-livereload", '~> 2.5', require: false
  gem "rack-livereload"
end
```

Initialize guard-livereload:

```
bundle exec guard init livereload
```

In config/enviroments/development add:

```
config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::Static, Rack::LiveReload
```

Finally, in run in a separate console:

```
bundle exec guard
```

In addition to your `rails server`.

Check the [guard-livereload repo](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) for more information.

- Tested in Rails 6